# Trouble Exporting JSON in Firebase Read-only & Non-realtime Mode

Tags: json, firebase, export, real-time, readonly

It seems like when the amount of data gets too large, Firebase goes into a "Read-only & Non-realtime Mode" which they didn't warn about. In this mode, the Export JSON does not work. I can go into each and every node to extract the JSON, but that will mean that I have to do for tens of nodes. How do I get the node (that is currently too large) to become real time again, or how do I export the JSON when it is non-realtime? Also, is Firebase still writable when it is in non-realtime?

Comment: What are the symptoms of the failure?  When I view a 12MB database that is in non-realtime mode using Chrome, the Export JSON menu item is enabled and downloads the file.

Comment: I originally tried using Firefox and Chrome to access the Export JSON menu item, but both returned a "File not found". Strangely, it is now working again and I am able to download my JSON file. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I sometimes see this message even though the download completes  successfully. 
 This seems to happen only the first time the export is requested:  _This site can’t be reached...
The webpage at `https://onyx-segment-999.firebaseio.com/.json?print=pretty&format=export&download=onyx-segment-770-export.json&auth=eyJAhR...IBQAY` might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address._

Answer (score 3):

I'm just face the problem that user8267710 mention above.
In my case (and I guess in Bob Snyder's) the problem only appears when you try to download the JSON from root, i.e. "/", the upper level.

I'm had success to download the full database tampering the download url.
When I tried to download from root the fail url is something like:

```
https://example.firebaseio.com/.json?print=pretty&format=export&download=example-export.json&auth=eyJhb...
```

If you change it adding a "/" before ".json" immediate after the db name, the link works as desired and all the data is downloaded ( at least in my case :-).
In the example case is:

```
https://example.firebaseio.com//.json?print=pretty&format=export&download=example-export.json&auth=eyJhb...
```

God Luck!

Comment: I'm just downloaded the same firebase today and looks like the problem was corrected (no error, no double / needed :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the console will stop reflecting updates to data in real time when your data set becomes too large.  If you need to download parts of your database outside the console, you can still use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/) to download any or all of your database.

Comment: and the Export JSON menu should also still work, right?

Comment: The Export JSON menu originally wasn't working and I got a "File not found" error when I tried to download the file. Strangely, it is suddenly working again after I posted this question. Thanks for your help nonetheless! But may I ask if the data will still be written onto the database even if firebase isn't real time?

Comment: All clients with listeners should always see realtime updates the data.  You can imagine that the console would be different than a typical client because it has to effectively listen to *all* the data, whereas clients typically listen to a small amount of it at any given moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the status of your application under https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings.

I was playing around with the Google Cloud Platform, and ended up disabling the App Engine. After enabling it again, Firebase Realtime Database's "Export JSON" function started working again instantly.